# Kafka Storm Integration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to integrate Kafka and Storm.

I have created a spout to read Kafka messages and emit them them as tuples.

While running the storm topology, I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.javaSerialize(Utils.java:87) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare non-serializable fields in your spout as transient. These fields should be initialized in open method of your spout.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It worked. But now i am getting the below exception java.lang.InterruptedException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
                                                                                                    This exception occured in the iterator i am using in nextTuple() method of the Spout.

Comment: You may be getting other exceptions as well. I don't have your code so I can't add more.